# How to change my wordpress domain name?

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting

I have my [WordPress site](https://silentsniffer.wordpress.com) hosted on WordPress server. Now, I have registered a new domain name say `example.ml`. How can I change the WordPress URL to new domain name?

Do I need to completely move my files to a new host to do this? Is it possible to add URL to a site hosted on WordPress.

Any help is entertained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could at least check the Wordpress Codex site. [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

You need to edit the WP-config.php

> define('WP_HOME','http://yournewdomain.com');
>   define('WP_SITEURL','http://yournewdomain.com');

Comment: And an important note found on the same link:   Both settings should include the http:// part and should not have a slash "/" at the end.

Comment: I don't understand how can I edit the codes. Only I have is the access to admin panel of wordpress. How can I get access to edit code?

Comment: If you really don't have any option to edit the config file (which is really weird), I suggest you to install the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-config-file-editor/  or contact the web admin who has proper access.